# How to include a excluded file in sub directory in Git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have two .gitignore files in the one in the root and another in the sub directory

Root Directory

```
*.vcproj
```

Sub Directory

```
!*.vcproj
```

So I want to include the *.vcproj in the sub directory but not in the root. But this doesn't to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add "/" before *.vcproj. This will ignore in the directory the file is in.

```
/*.vcproj
```

`.gitignore` patterns apply recursively to the directory the file is in and all its subdirectories unless preceded by `'/'`

`*.vcproj` will be ignored in all directories inluding subdirectories.

`/*.vcproj` will only be ignored in the same directory where `.gitignore` file is.